# Cloth simulation Vertex group Stiffness/plasticity/flexibility

Tags: cloth-simulation

I want to be able to use my weight paint to make parts of my cloth simulation less flexible than other sections and I haven't been able to find this option anywhere.

Comment: in your Physics panel > Cloth > Shape > Pin Group, choose your group

Comment: Pin group removes any movement for those areas. I still want physics applied, just not the same cloth properties. Pinning will only maken it hang from the very group instead of it all dropping.

Comment: don't give a weight of 1 to the vertices, try lower values

Comment: Thank you. That seams to be giving the result I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make a part of your object stiffer, weight paint this part with a low value (otherwise it will hang), it will automatically create a vertex group, choose this vertex group as the *Pin Group* of your cloth (*Cloth > Shape > Pin Group*).